# Thread pool sizing for network-bound tasks

Tags: networking, threadpool

What are the basic rules for sizing a thread pool which contains tasks that:

- are always network-bound;
- access external services with different throughput and latency.

My main concern is using the bandwith optimally ( *i.e.* don't process tasks serially, but don't open 1200 network connections either );

Comment: Are these network connections all open to the same endpoint, or to many different ones?

Answer (score 1):

Is your network access synchronous or asynchronous?

If your network access and request processing is asynchronous, then the thread pool size can be => Number of available cores + 1.

**UPDATE:** By available cores, I mean the number of physical processors available on the system. A thread pool is required even for a server using async I/O to take advantage of multiple physical processors.

If your network access and request processing is synchronous, then there is no hard-and-fast rule for sizing the thread pool. It is always better to make the thread pool size configurable in this case.
A guestimate for a default value, given that your request processing is not CPU bound, could be:

(Request Processing Latency/Network Latency) * (Number of Available cores + 1)
with a maximum value of 4 * Number of Avaliable cores.

Comment: Those threads do nothing but read network data from external sources. The CPU impact is minimal, so I don't see how the number of cores is taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but shouldn't you have one thread per task?
The threads will block/poll until data is available.
If you're waiting on a connection then start a thread to handle each connection in the connection handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a thread per task, but what measures would I use to estimate the number of tasks?